# Is there a easy way to sync content providers on phone and wearable

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, wear-os, sony-smartwatch

I have content provider on the phone, and I'd like to display content from this provider on watch. the only way I can see is send everything manually via https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html

which is not very cool, as all good mechanisms (content providers, SyncAdapters) that Android has are ignored

Comment: Did you find an elegant way of doing this? Just looking into the topic now.

Comment: Have to sync it manually, currently I've implemented one-way sync

Comment: @AndrewMatuk Is the code you wrote/used to implement one-way sync available somewhere for us to see?

Comment: @LouisCAD yes, but as you understand it's old code (year 2014) so it would be "as is"

Comment: @AndrewMatuk Content Providers and handset <-> wearables communication didn't changed since, so can still help, at least for inspiration. Could you link the "as is" code, please?

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13703737/veonua-notify-friends-android-1302f2b8fba2.zip